# Serialization Error when reading value with RedisTemplate and GenericJackson2RedisSerializer

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am trying a very basic example of Spring Data Redis, where I want to store a User object in Redis and then return it:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class BasicUser {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private String emailAddress;
        private Integer age;
}
```

```
@Test
    public void storeUserInRedisWithRedisTemplateTest() {
        BasicUser user = BasicUser
                        .builder()
                        .age(22)
                        .name("testuser")
                        .surname("testsurname")
                        .emailAddress("address@address.com")
                        .build();

        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("userWithTemplate", user, 10800);

        BasicUser returnedUser =  (BasicUser) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("userWithTemplate");
        assertThat(returnedUser.emailAddress, is(user.emailAddress));
    }
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x7b214063 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #2700, byte #10803); nested exception is java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x7b214063 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #2700, byte #10803)

    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeValue(AbstractOperations.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations$ValueDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(AbstractOperations.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:188)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.get(DefaultValueOperations.java:53)
    at com.kuluvalley.guru.server.service.UserSessionCacheServiceTest.storeUserInRedisWithRedisTemplateTest(UserSessionCacheServiceTest.java:123)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x7b214063 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #2700, byte #10803)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:250)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4340)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3266)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:150)
    ... 40 more
```

In Redis, the value looks like:

```
[MANY MORE 0x00]
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{\"@class\":\"com.org.BasicUser\",\"name\":\"testuser\",\"surname\":\"testsurname\",\"emailAddress\":\"address@address.com\",\"age\":22}"
```

The relevant Redis Configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(Environment env) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName(env.getRequiredProperty("redis.hostname"));
        configuration.setPort(env.getProperty("redis.port", Integer.class, 6379));
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate(Environment env) {
        StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory(env));
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }

}
```

I would expect this to just work as I am reading and writing the same data. Also the amount `0x00` is worrying. Is it best practice using Strings as values? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, because you are using the wrong api not expected:

- void set(K key, V value, long offset);

You should use:

- void set(K key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit);

with code:

- redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("userWithTemplate", user, 10800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: How is that that adding timeouts/timeunits in one method completely changes the result?

Comment: @DavidFernandez The error you faced is not because timeout not set, but offset got set, means you want to set the value with offset, which caused the value changed from the original one. FYI, if you don't set a timeout, it means to store the data permanently. If you need to do so, just call the API `void set(K key, V value)`.

Comment: Oh sorry I now see it, passing offset instead of TTL. I’ll test this, but I’ll accept your answer as it all makes more sense now. All those 0x0 are padding for the offset of 10800 I suppose.